# AAD Powershell command "Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment" returned opposite result when running under user context and SP context

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

I found the result of running Azure AD Powershell command "**Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment**" is different (opposite) when:
Connect Azure AD (Connect-AzureAD) as **user** context.
Connect Azure AD as **Service Principal** context.

The result of using Service Principal context is the same, no matter using powershell command, or Azure AD Graph query (`https://graph.windows.net/{tenantid}/servicePrincipals/{SPObjectId}/appRoleAssignments?api-version=1.6`). However, the result of using user context is different when using Powershell and Azure AD Graph query, even the query string is exact the same.

I compared the access token (user context, powershell and Azure AD Graph query) and found, the only significant differences are AppID and Scope. So I doubt maybe AAD backend has some code to handle this, if the AppID is Azure AD Powershell "**1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2**", the code will reverse the output and send to us.  Anyone has came across with similar issue before and has any thoughts? Thank you in Advance!

Comment: NEVER post images of code, output or errors! [mcve]

Comment: Which version of the `AzureAD` module are you using?

Comment: Hello Joy, I'm using Azure AD Powershell Preview, version 2.0.2.5. But this issue can be reproduced by other customers as well. So I don't think it's related to module version.

Comment: Well, looks like a bug, but i am not sure. I can reproduce the issue both in GA version or Preview version. If you also run `Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignedTo` with user context, you will find the results of the two commands are exactly the opposite of those with service principal context.

Comment: I think this is a designed behavior. But it would be great if you can help feedback this to the Product Group and get it confirmed.